# passing a variable to ajax after being changed in function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new so I apologize if I ask my question wrong. I have 3 drop down select boxes. The first allows you to select the width, the second is length and the third has the height. They have pre-selected values. Each value when selected is set to be changed to a width, length or height that is closest to. These are going to standard sizes saved in a database. After selection I can get the variable to change to the closest size but I cannot get them passed with AJAX. Here is the link to

```
<body onload="myFunction(),myFunction1(),myFunction3()">
<form name='myForm'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div align="center" class="one">
            <p>Select the Width.</p>Width:
            <select id="x" onchange="myFunction();">
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12" selected>12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="two">
            <p>Select the Length.</p>Length:
            <select id="l" onchange="myFunction1();">
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21" selected>21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
                <option value="32">32</option>
                <option value="33">33</option>
                <option value="34">34</option>
                <option value="35">35</option>
                <option value="36">36</option>
                <option value="37">37</option>
                <option value="38">38</option>
                <option value="39">39</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="41">41</option>
                <option value="42">42</option>
                <option value="43">43</option>
                <option value="44">44</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
                <option value="46">46</option>
                <option value="47">47</option>
                <option value="48">48</option>
                <option value="49">49</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="51">51</option>
                <option value="52">52</option>
                <option value="53">53</option>
                <option value="54">54</option>
                <option value="55">55</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="three">
            <p>Select the Height.</p>Height:
            <select id="h" onchange="myFunction3();">
                <option value="5" selected>5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="four">
            <p id="width"></p>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="five">
            <p>x</p>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="six">
            <p id="length"></p>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="seven">
            <p>x</p>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="eight">
            <p id="height"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center" class="eigth">
        <input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL' />
    </div>
</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv' align="center" class="eigth">Your result will display here</div>
</body>
```

This is my html above and here is the javascript below

```
function myFunction() {
var x = "";
x = document.getElementById("x").value;
if (x <= 12) {
    x = 12;
} else if ((x > 12) && (x < 19)) {
    x = 18;
} else if ((x > 18) && (x < 21)) {
    x = 20;
} else if ((x > 20) && (x < 23)) {
    x = 22;
} else if ((x > 22) && (x < 25)) {
    x = 24;
} else if ((x > 24) && (x < 27)) {
    x = 26;
} else if ((x > 26) && (x < 29)) {
    x = 28;
} else if ((x > 28) && (x < 31)) {
    x = 30;
}
document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = x;
}



function myFunction1() {
var l = "length";
l = document.getElementById("l").value;
if (l <= 21) {
    l = 21;
} else if ((l > 21) && (l < 27)) {
    l = 26;
} else if ((l > 26) && (l < 32)) {
    l = 31;
} else if ((l > 31) && (l < 37)) {
    l = 36;
} else if ((l > 36) && (l < 42)) {
    l = 41;
} else if ((l > 41) && (l < 47)) {
    l = 46;
} else if ((l > 46) && (l < 52)) {
    l = 51;
} else if ((l > 51) && (l < 57)) {
    l = 56;
}
 document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = l;
}

function myFunction3() {
var h = "";
h = document.getElementById("h").value;
document.getElementById("height").innerHTML = h;
}


//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction() {
var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try {
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data 
// sent from the server and will update
// div section in the same page.
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}


 // Now get the value from user and pass it to
 // server script.
 var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
 var length = document.getElementById('length').value;
 var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
 var queryString = "?width=" + width;
 queryString += "&length=" + length + "&height=" + height;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null);
 }
```

Here is the fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/steven27030/fNWEJ/47/

I am trying to make it so i can pull a price from the database with these 3 variables input by the user.

Here is the PHP code i will using with this.

```
 <?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "dbusername";
$dbpass = "dbpassword";
$dbname = "dbname";
//Connect to MySQL Server
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
//Select Database
   mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
// Retrieve data from Query String
  $width = $_GET['width'];
  $length = $_GET['length'];
  $height = $_GET['height'];
//build query
  $query = "SELECT price FROM ajax_example WHERE width = '$width' AND length = '$length'  
 AND height ='$height'";                                                                                       

//Execute query
  $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Build Result String
   $display_string = "<table>";
   $display_string .= "<tr>";
   $display_string .= "<th>Price</th>";
   $display_string .= "</tr>";

  // Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<td>$row[price]</td>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

   }
      echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
      $display_string .= "</table>";
   echo $display_string;
    ?>
```

Again I hope somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting the value of the wrong property. Instead of this:

```
var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
```

is this:

```
var width = document.getElementById('width').innerHTML;
```

Comment: glad it worked, but if you eliminate a lot of these elements and took the value directly from select

Comment: if i new how i would. But because you showed me how i now have took the program to almost the point i want it to be. If you want look at what ive done to it on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/steven27030/Cdn42/ also i have a live version here  http://tntcarports.tk/test2.html that has a few prices loaded in the database . again thank you the business i work at will be needing this program if i can finish it

Comment: that cleaned it up alot. thank you. is there a way to get it to fire the functions when i select the cateloge (my first drop down) instead of the button, and change as i update each selection? I need it not to fire the functions until the first drop down is selected. without that selection the rest should not fire the functions when changed until the first one is selected

Comment: if I understand well, just make the call of "ajaxFunction" function in the "onchange" of the elements

Comment: that worked now i will try to lock the other select boxes until the first one has a selection . again thank you